# How to retrieve all documents in a collection from firebase in Python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am unable to retrieve the documents which are available in my collection inside the firestore database. Here is my code. 
Every time I run this console dosen't print anything. I am following the documentation avaliable on this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data, but it dosen't seems to work.

```
database_2 = firestore.client()
all_users_ref_2 = database_2.collection(u'user').stream()
for users in all_users_ref_2:
  print(u'{} => {}'.format(users.id, users.to_dict()))
```

Comment: try firestore.Client() using Client()    ..."C" as capital letter

Answer (score 2):

Could be an authentication issue, you could download a service account key and use that in your project at the top.

```py
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALs"] = "path/to/key.json"
```

or as mentioned

```
database_2 = firestore.Client("<project ID>")
```

make sure `Client` is a capital C

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple projects? If so, double check that you open a client to the correct project. One quick way to confirm is to pass the project ID to the client:

```
db = firestore.Client('my-project-id')
```